# Ruby mixed array to nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I have a Ruby array whose elements alternate between Strings and Hashes. For example-

```
["1234", Hash#1, "5678", Hash#2]
```

I would like to create a nested hash structure from this. So,

```
hash["1234"]["key in hash#1"] = value
hash["5678"]["key in hash#2"] = value
```

Does anyone have/now a nice way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want here. Are you wanting to take every 2nd element from the array (which should be a hash) and create a key using the previous item in the array with a hash value that you create based on the existing keys in the original hash (2nd item in the array)?

Comment: the hashes may have more than one key/value, where would they go? try to use valid Ruby in the examples. It's easier if you say: 1) I have this array (real array) and 2) I want this result, and 3) That's what I've tried so far.

Comment: I've downvoted your question because it is unclear. If you edit your question to clarify what real data might look like, and what you want to occur with that data, I will happily reverse my vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use

```
hsh = Hash[*arr] #suppose arr is the array you have
```

It will slice 2 at a time and convert into hash.

Comment: You need `Hash[*arr]` but +1 for an otherwise excellent point!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a method on array to do this directly. The following code works and is quite easy to read.

```
hsh = {}

ary.each_slice(2) do |a, b|
  hsh[a] = b
end

# Now `hsh` is as you want it to be
```

Comment: Simpler: `hsh = Hash[ ary.each_slice(2).to_a ]` (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Guessing at what you want, since *"key in hash#1"* is not clear at all, nor have you defined what `hash` or `value` should be:

```
value = 42

h1 = {a:1}
h2 = {b:2}
a = ["1234",h1,"5678",h2]
a.each_slice(2).each{ |str,h| h[str] = value }
p h1, #=> {:a=>1, "1234"=>42}
  h2  #=> {:b=>2, "5678"=>42}
```

Alternatively, perhaps you mean this:

```
h1 = {a:1}
h2 = {b:2}
a = ["1234",h1,"5678",h2]

hash = Hash[ a.each_slice(2).to_a ]
p hash             #=> {"1234"=>{:a=>1}, "5678"=>{:b=>2}}
p hash["1234"][:a] #=> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

let's guess, using facets just for fun:

```
require 'facets'
xs = ["1234", {:a => 1, :b => 2}, "5678", {:c => 3}]
xs.each_slice(2).mash.to_h
#=> {"1234"=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}, "5678"=>{:c=>3}}
```

Comment: Already covered by ksol's answer (in a less-efficient form) and my answer (directly).

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with drawing from another answer to make the best possible answer. (I'm saying explicitly that you should add the `Hash[]` version to your answer, especially if you get the accept.) Previously your answer was just duplicative, but now it's +1able :)

Comment: @Phrogz: When I was writing it I only saw ksol's answer. And sure I don't like eachs to build a hash :-) thanks for the +1 in any case.